# Getting database adapter in a model in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am a zf1 developer. I started zf2. I am creating a Authentication module. I created a Auth class as mentioned in the doc

```
<?php
namespace Application\Model;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable as AuthAdapter;

class Myauth implements AdapterInterface {

    /**
     * Sets username and password for authentication
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($username, $password) {


        // Configure the instance with constructor parameters...
        $authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($dbAdapter,
        'users',
        'username',
        'password'
        );

        $authAdapter
        ->setTableName('users')
        ->setIdentityColumn('username')
        ->setCredentialColumn('password');


        $result = $authAdapter->authenticate();

        if (!$result->isValid()) {
            // Authentication failed; print the reasons why
            foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                echo "$message\n";
            }
        } else {
            // Authentication succeeded
            // $result->getIdentity() === $username
        }

    }
}
```

Issue1 : How to get $dbAdapter here?
Issue2 : Is this correct way to create auth module?

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser

Comment: @JonDay I implemented this. But I am not understanding the concepts used in it. I always sticks with Zf1. If there is large amount of customization I think it is better to create my own.

Comment: Well, ZfcUser should be understood before attempting to create your own Module. I mean there's literally no point in us telling you how to do things when you don't understand them. And we'd simply be telling you how ZfcUser does it so... you see the dilemma?

Comment: I went through the ZF-commons. I came to know that some basic modules are available here. 
User,Auth and Acl modules are important. Every one should use this for creating a web based application. And sure they have to customize it. That means we have to study the flow of these 3 modules. Ok I will do that. It sounds a little bit difficult if it has no common architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a couple things to say:

**1. About Database Adapter**

This [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable) shows you how to configure database adapter.

In config/autoload/global.php:

```
 return array(
 'db' => array(
     'driver'         => 'Pdo',
     'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=zf2tutorial;host=localhost',
     'driver_options' => array(
         PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
     ),
 ),
 'service_manager' => array(
     'factories' => array(
         'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                 => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
     ),
 ),
);
```

In config/autoload/local.php:

```
 return array(
     'db' => array(
         'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
         'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
     ),
 )
```

Now, from ServiceLocatorAware classes, you can get Database Adapter as

```
$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
```

**2. About Creating Authentication**

Dude, why reinvent the square wheel? As mentioned [here](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/ZfcUser-Concepts-and-Goals), [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) is built to be a foundation for a very large percentage for Zend Framework 2 applications.

Nearly anything is customizable as mentioned [here](http://hounddog.github.io/blog/there-is-a-module-for-that/). A lot of modules are available such as [ScnSocialAuth](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth) which have dependancy on ZfcUser and are really awesome.

Answer (score 1):

As in ZF 2, Models are not ServiceLocatorAware classes, so you cannot use the solution in Ojjwal Ojha's answer.

You can:
1. Get dbAdapter in your Controller by calling:

> `$dbAdapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');`

2. Pass dbAdapter to your Model when you create it:

   > `$model = new Model($dbAdapter)`;
3. Write an init function in your Model.